# Cannot open worklight app in ipad

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I installed ipa for a worklight application in iOS8 ipad. While opening the application it is showing error as "Cannot find 'app-name''version'in this ipad". What could be the reason for this??

Comment: Add some missing information... Did you compile this app yourself? Does it happen with a new app as well? How did you add the .ipa to the iPad?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the project is being incorrectly signed/generated in Xcode. Possibly due to wrongly given values.

When you create a new project in Worklight Studio > add iPhone environment > Build > Open in Xcode > Run, does the app get successfully installed and launched in the iOS Simulator/device? My guess would be that 'yes'.

Open the info plist file and verify the application parameters are correct. Have you changed these? or anything else?